# Local Notification for Alarm Snooze

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, alarm

I am working on an alarm application and I am using local notification for that. Now I want to add snooze functionality to my alarm and alert show minimum distance 1 minute.

I am set Multiple alarm in my application so how can I managed it's?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/azu/SnoozeLocalNotification

Answer (score 0):

`UILocalNotification` instances have a `userInfo` property of type `NSDictionary`. This can be used for storing information that you can later use for identifying what the notification was for.

For example, you could add the following code before firing the notification:

```
notification.userInfo = @{kAlarmIdentifier: alarm.identifier"};
```

where `kAlarmIdentifier` is a constant string used as a key. Then, when the notification is triggered, you can get the alarm that caused it with something like:

```
MYAlarm *alarm = [alarmManager getAlarmForIdentifier:notification.userInfo[kAlarmIdentifier]];
```

Comment: how to manage snooze time if click on snooze at 4:58 am and i want next alarm time has 5:58 am but alarm alert on 5:00 am. how to solved it.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're asking - are you saying the initial notification fired at 4:58am but the user didn't click on it until 5am?

Comment: set UILocalNotification for multipal notification at a time?

Comment: if I click on snooze of first alarm for 1 minute(now next fire time is 5am) and set second alarm for 5:01am but both time alert only for first alarm.How can I solve it?